# Requisição POST no retrofit2

Tags: android

Como faço pra enviar dados de um formulário no android usando retrofit2?
Da forma como estou fazendo as informações armazenadas no banco estão sendo enviadas através de uma passagem por parâmetro, gostaria de recuperar os dados de um EditText por exemplo, alguém pode me ajuda?

Segue abaixo meu código usando o retrofit2:

```
> Call<Usuario> call = usuarioAPI.criaUsuario(new
> Usuario("login","senha","nome"));
>     call.enqueue(new Callback<Usuario>() {
>         @Override
>         public void onResponse(Response<Usuario> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
> 
>             if (!response.isSuccess()) {
>                 response.body().getLogin();
>                 Log.i("TAG", "POST Erro: " + response.code());
>             } else {
>                 Log.i("TAG", "POST Sucesso: " + response.code());
>             }
>         }
> 
>             @Override
>             public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
>                 Log.i("TAG", "Erro no método onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
>             }
>     });
```